# mvn tomcat:run default war to use

Tags: maven, build

I have the following project structure.

```
Proj
|_ pom.xml
|_ WebApp1
|  |_ pom.xml
|_ WebApp2
   |_pom.xml
```

From the project level if I run mvn tomcat:run, maven deploys my WebApp1 to tomcat container. However, I need to run WebApp2 by default. I can't change the build order of webapp1 and webapp2.

Any suggestions??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the order of the modules in your Proj POM from

```
<modules>
  <module>WebApp1</module>
  <module>WebApp2</module>
<modules>
```

to

```
<modules>
  <module>WebApp2</module>
  <module>WebApp1</module>
<modules>
```

Bu why do you start the Tomcat from your project's root level? If you run the tomcat plugin within the WebApp2 module it should only start WebApp2.